# How to pass variables from a controller to a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
   $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }
```

I have this code in my controller for example. I was wondering how I can pass `$nameErr` to my view HTML?

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
```

Comment: Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>

Sorry there is something missing

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution? Why does it not do what you want to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you use codeigniter form validation and pass errors that way. don't use $_POST name on codeigniter use $this->input->post('name') Library form validation here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html and form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifing the view name in your code (controller)

According to : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

You have to use: $this->load->view('view_name', $nameErr);

Comment: Are you sure to go through `if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {`  ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 // Don't Use $_POST[] use $this->input->post()

 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]); 

 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
   $data['nameErr'] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }

 $this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

To submit post you need **codeigniter form_validation** [Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) you can also use callback function which I would recommend.

**Controller Example Functions Form Validation Callback**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

 function index() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required|callback_checkname');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('your_view');
    } else {
        // redirect('success_page');
    }
 }

 function checkname() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $name = $this->input->post('name');

    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('checkname' ,"Only letters and white space allowed"); 
       return false;
    }
  }
}
```

View Example

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url('login');?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```